# how to display Persian date in webform module

Tags: 6, webforms, datetime

I have problems to display a Persian date (Jalali Calendar System) with the Webform module

The errors I get are the following:

> The entered date must be @start_date or later.
>   The entered date must be @end_date or earlier.

I want to be displayed in the yaer field  (1350  to Current year)

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? For example, what is the Persian calendar you're using, and what dates are you trying to put into the webform?

Comment: It seams you have problem in webform validation, when user are filling form, am I right?

Comment: yes i have problem in webform validation

Comment: How do I correct it